# JSON api data not loading in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

So I'm fairly new to using React and I've been given an assignment to fetch data from a JSON API and display it on the screen. While practicing fetching data for https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users everything was working correctly and I was getting no errors. Once I tried to get data from this api https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students.

I got this massive error in my console (I did cut some of the eror message out because it was really huge).

Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function

> ```
> at App.render (App.js:34)
> at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15141)
> at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15096)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15980)
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19102)
> at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19143)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
> at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:18350)
> at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:19261)
> at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20165)
> at performWork (react-dom.development.js:20075)
> at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:20049)
> at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:19904)
> at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:19711)
> at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:12936)
> at
> ```

App.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:356)
    at App.js:16

So my question is how come I could get the data from one api but not the other? Is there something wrong with the other api or am I doing something incorrectly? I will post my code below.

> > import React, {Component} from 'react';
> >
> > ```
> > class App extends Component{
> >     constructor(props){
> >         super(props);
> >         this.state = {
> >             items:[],
> >             isLoaded: false
> >         };
> >     }
> > ```
>
> ```
>   componentDidMount(){
>       fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students')
>           .then(res=> res.json())
>           .then(json =>{
>               this.setState({
>                   isLoaded: true,
>                   items: json,
>               })
>           });
>   }
>
>
>   render(){
>       const {isLoaded, items} = this.state;
>       if(!isLoaded){
>           return <div>loading data...</div>;
>       }
>
>       else{           
>
>           return(
>               <div className="Data">
>                   <ul>
>                       {items.map(item=>(
>                           <li key={item.students}>
>                               name:{item.name}
>                           </li>
>                       ))};
>                   </ul>                   
>               </div>
>
>           );
>        }
>
>   }
>
> }
>
> export default App;
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students` API returns an object with `students` property.

So your `items` is an object, and not an array, that is why it does not have `map` function.

To fix the problem your fetch logic can look like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
      fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students')
          .then(res=> res.json())
          .then(({ students }) => {
              this.setState({
                  isLoaded: true,
                  items: students,
              })
          });
  }
```